# ReadTheDocs refresh tags and versions

Tags: github, read-the-docs

Because we've done some rearranging of our documentation setup, I have two separate read the docs projects which I need to build from the same GitHub repo. One of them is brand new, and the other used to be pointed to the old repo.

I have set up a webhook on each project, and added both these webhooks to the repo.

The problem is that in the project that used to be pointed to the old repo, the stable build is still associated with the SHA of the latest release on the old repo, which does not exist in the new repo. This causes the `stable` build to fail.

One other thing I hope to solve, when activating some of the new versions (which used to exist in the old repo) an "_a" is added to then of the published version name, even though there are not multiple publishable versions with the same name.

I'm wondering: is it possible to completely refresh all of the RTD-detected versions and tags? I think doing so would solve both these issues.

I've tried "wiping" the builds but that doesn't help, I have read the RTD docs on versions many times, and I've triggered new push events from github (which are sent and received successfully) but still can't make any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this turned out to be just recreating the RTD projects. If anyone else comes across this issue, you could check out the ticket I made on the RTD repo https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/3763.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger a Build on any of the existing versions that RTD knows about. After that build job starts the Versions list will be updated from the git repo.

Comment: This reminded me that I found a simpler way to do this, I've updated my answer.